# What does the MySQL function name 'ELT' stand for?

Tags: mysql

I understand what the function 'ELT' does but what does it stand for? It doesn't state in the [official documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_elt) and I can't seem to find it anywhere else either.

Comment: Heh, interesting question! The only database-related acronym that I can see for ELT is [Extract, Load, Transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ELT) but I can't see how that would make sense

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It stands for "Eagle, lettuce and tomato," the least-successful sandwich ever made.

Seriously, I believe it's just an abbreviation of "element," as in, give me the nth element of the following list.

Answer (score 6):

The [wikipedia page for ELT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ELT) suggests it might mean this:

> Extract, Load, Transform (ELT), a data manipulation process; in ELT, data is extracted, loaded into the database, and transformed where it sits in the database, prior to use; a different approach to loading data than the commonly known Extract, transform, load (ETL)

Answer (score 1):

maybe "Element"? But following MySQL naming conventions I highly suspect the E to be from `Extract` or `Explode`.